# Wordpress set custom value in global variable

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I set a global variable in Wordpress with custom value. I would like to set branchId of the user when they login with 'wp_login' hook.

But I was not able to make it working. Here is the code:

```
function sp_setBranch() {
    // Set branch ID
    global $sp_branch, $wpdb, $current_user;
    if ($current_user->roles[0] == 'trainer'){
        $trainer_table=$wpdb->prefix.'sp_trainer';
        $branch=$wpdb->get_row("select branch_id from $trainer_table where wp_usr_id=$current_user->ID");
        $sp_branch = $branch->branch_id;
    } else {
         $sp_branch=58;
    }
}
add_action('wp_login','sp_setBranch');
```

Later I tried to get `$sp_branch` but I didn't receive value anywhere. I go for global because I need this anywhere.